# Swashbuckle pass Auth Bearer Token to API

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

Does Swashbuckle have any documentation on how to pass the bearer token to API , I am not able to pass the bearer token after upgrading to latest swashbuckle ver 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [blogged about this before](https://mattfrear.com/2018/07/21/add-an-authorization-header-to-your-swagger-ui-with-swashbuckle-revisited/).

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new ApiKeyScheme
    {
        Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
        In = "header",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = "apiKey"
    });

    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
```

You'll need a copy of SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter, which you can find by googling, or install from my [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/) package.

Comment: In my case , I need to store the bearer token returned after authenication(oAuth) and then pass on the same for further requests from Swagger UI. 
Any Ideas on how to store and process the bearer token, I have already followed all steps mentioned on your blog post.